# Drop row with spesific string

Tags: python, pandas, row, multiple-columns

I have huge data frame:

```
Data1   Data2
A       BS2
A       BS3
B       BS6
B       BS7
C       BS7
C       BS6
D       BS8
D       BS3
E       BS7
E       BS6
```

I just want to eliminate or drop row with a pair of data from data1 and "BS7 and BS6" from data2.

my expected result:

```
Data1   Data2
A       BS2
A       BS3
B       BS6
B       BS7
D       BS8
D       BS3
```

thank you for helping me

Comment: Why B did not get dropped

Comment: @WeNYoBen because B is "BS 6 to BS7" not "BS7 to BS6"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same logic before using `transform` slightly different we need `join` this time

```
df[df.groupby('Data1').Data2.transform(','.join).ne('BS7,BS6')]
Out[514]: 
  Data1 Data2
0     A   BS2
1     A   BS3
2     B   BS6
3     B   BS7
6     D   BS8
7     D   BS3
```

Comment: I am sorry again, what is 'ne' means?

Comment: @Arief ne means !=

Comment: @Arief happy coding :-)